# Calling Public Class function inside another public class function

Tags: php, function, class

I have created a class with public functions that returns form which includes select tag, and in this tag I want to call another function which will echo a list of data from MySQL database.

The issue is when I call the function in select tag or div tag the results show out of the whole form.

Here is the code I tried.

this is the clsses.php

```
<?php
global $conn,$CFG;
require_once __DIR__.'/../class/functions.php';
class form
{
    public function add_emp(): string
    {
        $function = new functions();
        return '
            <form class="form-control" name="emp-view" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="empmenu">
                    <nav class="emp-menu" id="emp-menu">
                        <a class="btn emp-nav active" href="#personalinfo" onclick="show_personalinfo()"><b>البيانات الشخصية</b></a>
                        <a class="btn emp-nav" href="#jobinfo" onclick="show_jobinfo()"><b>البيانات الوظيفية</b></a>
                        <a class="btn emp-nav" href="#workinfo" onclick="show_workinfo()"><b>بيانات جهة العمل</b></a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="personalinfo" id="personalinfo">
                    <div class="mainprofile">
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--             column 1-->
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label id="fullname">الاسم بالكامل</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" for="fullname" name="fullname" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--             column 1-->
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label>الرقم القومى</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="nationalid" required maxlength="14" minlength="14">
                                </div>
                                <!--             column 1-->
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label>الرقم التأمينى</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="ensuranceid" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--             column 1-->
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label>تاريخ الميلاد</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" required>
                                </div>
                                <!--             column 2-->
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label>محل الاقامة</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    '.$function->provinces().'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <!--submit button-->
                <div class="row action-btn">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-save" name="add" value="" id="add-btn"> اضافــة</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        ';
    }
}
```

this is the functions.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../config.php';
class functions
{
    public function provinces(): void
    {
        global $conn;
        $sql="select id,provincename from tblprovinces";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows) {
            echo '<select class="form-select" name="gov" id="gov" required>
                   <option  value="" >اختر</option>';
            while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<option value='.$row["id"].'>'.$row["provincename"].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }
}
```

this is vars.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../class/classes.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../class/functions.php';

$form = new form();
$function = new functions();
```

this is index.php

```
<?php
global $form, $function;
require_once __DIR__.'/../class/vars.php';

echo $form->add_emp();
```

Comment: Generally speaking, mixing and matching `echo` and returns with functions is really confusing and can lead to problems, and even more so when using classes. My recommendation would be to have your class methods **only** return values, never `echo`, or if you feel you must `echo`, pick a single class that is your "presentation logic", and it can do that.

Comment: I mean no disrespect when I say this, but this looks like OOP for the sake of OOP. If you have a class called "functions" that just holds functions, just use regular functions. The fact that you are also including global variables shows that you are fighting an uphill battle with your current code. Just my two cents.

Comment: Your code _should_ return value when it used in concatenation of strings, like this : `'.$function->provinces().'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a form, you do not insert your `<select>` tag into it as expected, but display it. You first have a dropdown list displayed and then the form is returned.

functions.php

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../config.php';
class functions {
    public function provinces(): string {
        global $conn;
        $sql="select id,provincename from tblprovinces";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        $element = '';
        if ($result->num_rows) {
            $element .= '<select class="form-select" name="gov" id="gov" required>
                   <option  value="" >اختر</option>';
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $element .= '<option value=' . $row['id'] . '>' . $row['provincename'] . '</option>';
            }
            $element .= '</select>';
        }
        return $element;
    }
}
```